# How can I use a local fork of angular material with my angular 6 app?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material2

I would like to make some changes to the angular material2 source code and have them reflected in my angular 6 application.

Currently the package.json file for my app specifies the following:

`“@angular/material”: “^6.4.3”`

I have tried cloning the project into a local folder and changing my apps package.json as follows:

`“@angular/material”:”file:../../material2”`

But then when running npm install, it fails with various missing directory errors.

It would appear that I am doing something completely wrong, but being very new to npm, I just don’t know what.

So, how can I use a local fork of angular-material2 with an angular 6 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on how you make the local fork available. Is it a published somewhere as a node package? Is the distribution build stored in a git repo? Is it just source code?

If you just need to "redirect" your app to point to a local directory instead of the node_modules package, maybe the easiest option is to use the tsconfig.json paths option. Something like:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
        "@angular/material": [
            "fork/material2",
            "../node_modules/@angular/material"
        ]
    },
}
```

This sets up a an ordered hierarchy of where to fetch the package. Not sure if this has changed, but it used to be that Angular CLI would only support this if the path was a descendent of your project root.

Another option is to look into `npm link`. In a nutshell, this replaces the node module package with whatever the package name is 'linked' to. I found it a bit tricky to wrap my head around the documentation for this, but it worked perfectly for me when I needed to do the same thing you are doing.